# Excessive A/C condensate on outsideof box

Tags: hvac

When running the A/C on my 2011 Chevy 2500 Duramax the outside of the heater box gets saturated in condensate. After 1 hour of running i'll have a 1/4" deep puddle on the passenger floor. It's not a drain problem. I replaced the orfice tube and same thing. Theres more condensate on the outside of the box than the inside, never seen this before. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You replace the orifice tube, but did you clean the drain hole?

Comment: @paulster2 Funny story, customer had a car making a sloshing sound in the dash, water in the box. I pulled the drain tube and unwisely put it up to my lips and blew through it. Spiders... To the OP does the A/C work correctly otherwise? You say it's not the drain, but as far as we know it very well could be. Can you provide pictures of the problem? What's the in cabin temp vs evaporator temp?

Comment: @Ben - Funny story ... my 94 Z28 had a blocked drain hole. Buddy decided he was going to help me clean it out. He stuffed a coat hanger up there and promptly got a face full of water, lol. As shocking as that was for him, I think that's a little more pleasant than finding spiders ;-)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:  Run your A/C in "Max A/C" or "Recirc" mode.

Condensate on the outside of the box?  That certainly is possible.  But....

That tells me clearly that you can easily fix the issue, while improving air conditioning cooling and while improving fuel economy (albeit just slightly) in a very simple way.

Instead of running your system in "Normal" Air Conditioning (A/C) mode, try running it in "Max A/C" or "Recirculate" mode.  The Max A/C mode does one thing.  It shuts the recirculation door in the air handling box inside the dash panel. That door shuts off outside air, and instead recirculates the air inside the vehicle.  It does nothing to the compressor or any other refrigerant controls.  It just changes one air handling door from outside fresh air to inside recirculation.

[image: HVAC Recirc vs Fresh Air Inlet]

Well how does that work?  In Fresh Air mode, you are drawing air from outside the vehicle, cooling it. In hot, humid weather, a good portion of air conditioning cooling energy is condensing water vapor.  You keep doing this, continually cooling air, removing water vapor.

In recirculation mode, instead of taking in hot, humid outside air, you are using the air inside the passenger compartment.  After ten minutes or so, the humidity inside the passenger compartment is totally removed.  And instead of trying to cool 105 degree hot humid air, you are now cooling 85 degree dry air, and then 84 degree dry air, then 83 degree dry air, and then 82...etc...  The A/C compressor load will go down, saving wear and tear on your vehicle.  You will get cooler faster and be more comfortable quicker.

Are there any downsides to using Recirc mode?  Yup.  You can't park your dirty stinky gym bag on the floor in front of the passenger seat.  The recirc inlet is just above that area.  And your Aunt Mable with the smelly feet? She will have to ride in the back.

And if you are seeing lots of condensate on the outside of your air handling box while in "Max A/C" or Recirc mode, then I'm telling you that your recirc door is broken and stuck in the fresh air position. You need to get that fixed.

Note: On the topic of recirc mode... at this point I'm talking about recirc mode in the hot summer when you want to cool your vehicle.  In the winter, this is a totally different conversation. You definitely want Fresh Air mode in the winter.  Recirc mode is downright dangerous.  In snowy or wet conditions (think snow all over your boots melting) the recirculation of melted snow / water will immediately condense on the inside of your windshield, blocking your ability to see and drive. This is not safe.  Stick with fresh air mode in the winter.